# Does TLS(Transport layer security) support HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, poodle-attack

I am going to change SSLv3 to TLS 1.0 due to the vulnerability available on SSLv3 (https://access.redhat.com/articles/1232123) 
I am not sure whether TLS 1.0 can support HTTPS?  Please advise me on this. 
Official documents written by seniors in this field are welcome

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. It is not about programming but about a basic understanding of the relationship between SSL/TLS and HTTPS. Please inform yourself about the basics of HTTPS, maybe at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure)

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is pretty much HTTPS who totally support (or `use` would be a better word?) TLS, and even SSL from time to time :-)